# Batch File "if not" error

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, directory

So I done a batch file edit with several options, I am trying to edit it so that if a number that is not in the file is picked it will return an error.

However when I run it, it does what I want it to do but anything above option 2 will return the error echo.

```
@echo off

title Multi-Game Launcher

set ARMA3_PATH=C:\Program Files\Steam\SteamApps\common\Arma 3
set ARMA2_PATH=E:\Games\Retail Games\Bohemia Interactive\ArmA 2
set ARMA2OA_PATH=E:\Games\Retail Games\Bohemia Interactive\ArmA 2
set TAKEONH_PATH=E:\Games\Retail Games\Bohemia Interactive\Take On Helicopters

:home
cls

echo.
echo Select a version:
echo =================
echo.
echo Which version would you like to run?
echo 1 - ArmA 2 ACE/ACRE
echo 2 - ArmA 2 DayZ
echo 3 - ArmA 2 I44
echo 4 - ArmA 3 AIA
echo 5 - ArmA 2 DayZ Chernarus Server
echo 6 - Exit

set /p version=Pick Version:

if %version%==1 (
    set CUSTOM_MODS=expansion\beta;expansion\beta\expansion;
    set DEFAULT_PARAMETERS=
    cd /D "%ARMA2OA_PATH%"
    start expansion\beta\arma2oa.exe %DEFAULT_PARAMETERS% "-mod=%CUSTOM_MODS%"
)

if  %version%==2 (
    set CUSTOM_MODS=expansion\beta;expansion\beta\expansion;@DayZ;BAF;PMC;ACR
    set DEFAULT_PARAMETERS=-noSplash -noFilePatching -winxp
    cd /D "%ARMA2OA_PATH%"
    start expansion\beta\arma2oa.exe %DEFAULT_PARAMETERS% "-mod=%CUSTOM_MODS%"
) 

if  %version%==3 (
    set CUSTOM_MODS=expansion\beta;expansion\beta\expansion;@I44;BAF;PMC;ACR
    set DEFAULT_PARAMETERS=-noSplash -noFilePatching -winxp
    cd /D "%ARMA2OA_PATH%"
    start expansion\beta\arma2oa.exe %DEFAULT_PARAMETERS% "-mod=%CUSTOM_MODS%"
) 

if  %version%==4 (
    set CUSTOM_MODS=@CBA_A3;@vts_weaponresting;@cal68
    set DEFAULT_PARAMETERS=
    cd /D "%ARMA3_PATH%"
    start arma3.exe %DEFAULT_PARAMETERS% "-mod=%CUSTOM_MODS%;@AllInArma\ProductDummies;%ARMA2_PATH%;%ARMA2OA_PATH%;%ARMA2OA_PATH%\Expansion;%TAKEONH_PATH%;@A1A2ObjectMerge;%ARMA3_PATH%;@AllInArma\Core;@AllInArma\PostA3"
)

if  %version%==5 (
    set CUSTOM_MODS=expansion\beta;expansion\beta\expansion;@DayZ;@reality_1.chernarus
    set DEFAULT_PARAMETERS= -BEPath=%INFO_PATH%\BattlEye -config=%INFO_PATH%\config.cfg -Profiles=%INFO_PATH% -cfg=%INFO_PATH%\basic.cfg
    cd /D "%ARMA2OA_PATH%"
    start expansion\beta\arma2oaserver.exe %DEFAULT_PARAMETERS% "-mod=%CUSTOM_MODS%"
)

if  %version%==6 (
    exit
)

if not "%version%"=="" (
echo Invalid Selection 
pause 
goto home 
)
```

Comment: It looks like the error output would be printed for *any* input except `6`. Is it really only showing for > 2?

Comment: You're right, it only works for 6. The error is displayed for every other. How do I make it (without copying + pasting that last line under each option thus making the code look messy) so that the error returns for any number that is not in the options. I used the "gtr" function which worked, but I would prefer it to grab the numbers dynamically instead of setting them myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the "switch statement" you have made around `%version%` always goes through `if not "%version%"==""` (except when option 6 is chosen), so the error is printed.

This means there are two things you can do:

1. Make sure the offending code is not executed if a valid option has been chosen
2. Make sure the conditional will not be true

I recommend going the first way by writing `goto :eof` at the end of each of your switch cases:

```
if %version%==1 (
    rem ...stuf....
    goto :eof
)
```

This way it's clear how the code flows, and of course you can use another label to jump to if there is reason to.

Comment: @downvoter: Please help me improve this answer by leaving a comment.

Answer (score 2):

inside a code block you need `delayed expansion`:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
if %version%==1 (
     set CUSTOM_MODS=expansion\beta;expansion\beta\expansion;
     set DEFAULT_PARAMETERS=
     cd /D "%ARMA2OA_PATH%"
     start expansion\beta\arma2oa.exe !DEFAULT_PARAMETERS! "-mod=!CUSTOM_MODS!"
)
```